# 403 Permission Denied

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403

1)  We have some code that works fine on our local web server, as per:
    http:// localhost/project1/start.htm

2)  This code is all inside the folder project1.  We have moved this whole folder to the root of our domain via Filezilla, so we now have:  www.mydomain.com/project1

3)  Here's the file structure:
    project1 (main folder) --> start.htm
    project1 (main folder) --> Player1 (sub-folder) --> class.htm

4)  When I type in the URL:  http:// www.mydomain.com/project1/start.htm

```
It works fine and brings up the hyperlink "start the course"
```

5)  When I click on "start the course" I get:

403 Permission Denied
You do not have permission for this request 
  /project1/Player1/class.htm

I read somewhere that I might have to give privileges to an .htaccess file but I'm not sure if this is the problem or how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

try chmod 755 for Player1 and files/folders under it..